# Can I create a b-source in a statement instead of using a graphical element in LT Spice?

Tags: ltspice, voltage-source

I currently do this, a lot in LT Spice:

[image]

Is there an alternative way to write an equation and have it end up in a node in LT spice and not use a graphical element, I would like to put it in one or two lines of spice directives.

I am aware of .param statements.

Comment: Do you want a behavioral voltage source, in particular? Because I don't know why you can't just use a spice line for that, instead of the symbol, if so. That's all the symbol does, anyway. May I guess that you've never tried to use /View/SPICE Netlist before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't said much yet. I'll just write.

As with all schematic editors combined with Spice simulators, the schematic editor is just there for human factors issues. Back in the day, it was all just punched out on cards and subjected to a card reader and some programming, which then in the best of cases would use a line printer and little '*' characters to plot curves if you wanted that. Wasted tons of paper that way.

Nothing has changed since then. Spice still uses a card deck and although some folks have deprecated the little '*' printing capability and replaced it with graphical routines for modern displays, the old line printer code is still there, too.

Anything you draw -- everything you draw -- just results in a card.

Your symbol included.

So in your case, it will generate this deck card:

```
B1 Vin2 0 V=V(Vin)*2
```

That's all it really does.

The "B is always in the first column. (Yes, we are still in the days when the column matters.) That identifies the SPICE model package to use. ('X' specifies to go look for .SUBCKT names, instead.) The characters or letters that follow it, before the first space, indicate the name you assign it. Then there are the names of each pin in whatever order is specified by the selected SPICE model. The number of pins is also specified by the model. In this case, just two of them. The pin called '0' is special and ALWAYS means ground. But you don't have to have a '0' assigned. You can write any pin names you want. The rest are given as parameters to the model.

Since the card deck is all that Spice uses, anyway, you can use any node names you want. It automatically creates the node labels based on the names you use. If you make up a new node label name, that does NOT cause any difficulties at all. It just means there's one more node in the schematic with the name you gave it. That's all.

So, just hit the 'S' key in LTspice and it will pop up this:

[image]

Then just paste or type in that line, *"B1 Vin2 0 V=V(Vin)*2"*, but without the quotes and then press OK.

You will then have a text thing at the tip of your text-mouse-cursor that you can move around and place anywhere on your schematic.

That's all there is to it.

If ever you care about all those little generated cards, you can just use the View menu and select "SPICE Netlist" and it will give all that to you in a nice text box in a dialog. You can copy and paste it, if you want.

You can also use the View menu's "SPICE Error Log" when you want to see still more, such as calculated values for the SPICE card deck as well as other outputs that you may have requested and error messages, of course.

Remember. Spice does ***NOT*** run a simulation on your schematic. It ***ONLY*** runs a simulation using the Spice card deck. The visual widgets on the schematic generate cards. The cards on the schematic *also* generate cards. So you can have a schematic without symbols and only cards, or a schematic with only symbols and no cards, or a schematic with any mixture between those two extremes. But it is all cards in the end. That's all the Spice simulator sees.

Comment: I figured as much but I'm trying to go for the question badge (and it's good for other people to read in the future SE, wants us to ask questions).

Comment: @VoltageSpike You sneaky guy!

Comment: +1, and a minor side comment: at least as far as LTspice is concerned, if the behavioural expression has only simple arithmetic multipliers or divisors, it might better to use the VCVS/VCCS primitives with the equivalent value. This is because of the hidden `tripdv, tripdt`, which can hinder (or not help enough) depending on the dynamic ranges involved (be they values or temporal).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen That's what crossed my mind when I wrote my first comment to Voltage. I wondered if he really wanted a B source. It's not always the best choice. It's just really versatile, that's all.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I'm aware of the dynamic range problem, I usually normalize the signals if I have to with a function or constant